# Box2d c++ what is the similar to ActionScript b2Body SetPosition?

Tags: c++, actionscript, box2d

i tring to port some code from ActionScript to c++ box2d
the code from ActionScript is from 2011 so im not sure which version of box2d its using .
im using the latest .
any way this is what i have in action script :

```
    var leftAxle:b2Body=world.CreateBody(leftAxleBodyDef);
    leftAxle.CreateFixture(leftAxleFixture);
// this is the part i need to port , there is no SetPosition in the box2d 2.2+ version 
    leftAxle.SetPosition(new b2Vec2(carPosX/worldScale-axleContainerDistance/worldScale-axleContainerHeight/worldScale*Math.cos((90-axleAngle)*degreesToRadians),carPosY/worldScale+axleContainerDepth/worldScale+axleContainerHeight/worldScale*Math.sin((90-axleAngle)*degreesToRadians)));
```

basclly its box with Hypotenuse angle

Comment: the current release on box2dflash.org is v2.1a, so it should still be the same - have you tested it?

Comment: its the one in cocos2d-x , i think its the latest 
no SetPosition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, thought you were converting from C++ to AS3

A quick look at the code: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/ac2c0469c71eaabff38f545ce956859627f2b7fc/external/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp

It seems like `SetPosition()` is now `SetTransform(const b2Vec2& position, float32 angle)`. This is because they're stocking the position and rotation as a `b2Transform` behind the scenes. Even the `GetPosition()` is just returning the `position` property of the `b2Transform`